# better way between ivy maven or gradle

Tags: maven, ant, gradle

I have a doubt and i want to expose it to clear my mind and have a better idea on how solve my problem.
I need to build a big *repository* for large amount of projects that a team of programmers have done in a lot of years. These projects are a lot of *webapp*. Substantially i need to build a *repository* that can **interface with build.xml** needs of libraries.
Until now all the work that has been done was done with `ant`, so instinctively i was near to decide to use `ivy` to do that, but i have read some documentation about `maven` and `gradle`, that could cover this scope.
The reason why i'm analysing these two instruments is that they are more recent and maybe they could have some good features, but the idea that i have about these is the sequent:

- `Maven:` it's probably the most right insturment that i could use to do what i need, but maven structures is a little bit rigid to be so sure that i will not found problems with the actual structures of the projects.
- `Gradle:` it uses a completely different language from xml, so first i need to learn it and second i have not really clear what's the way how it interact with the ant build
  any suggestions?

Comment: Ivy is a dependency management tool. Maven and Gradle are build tools that include dependency management. Gradle's dependency management supports both Maven and Ivy repositories.

Comment: so basing on your affermation, i suppose that gradle is the best way to renew the system's projects and can include the old work?

Comment: If you want a modern build tool and still use the existing Ivy repo, Gradle is usually a good choice. However, you should always do your own evaluation and proof-of-concept. PS: I'm one of the Gradle(ware) developers.

Comment: before making the question i was allready a little bit from the part of that choice, especially because i begin to realize that it will not be so difficult to transport the old project, thanks for the answer and the honesty.